# chamilo-lms blank page and error after installation

Tags: php, error-handling, symphony-cms, chamilo-lms

I am new to chamilo installation, I am having this issue after the installation with chamilo-lms. After I login, and try to go to home page, it becomes a blank page. Also, when clicking on Calendar/Administration for example I receive these errors:

I would be very grateful If someone could help me with same directions. Thanks a lot!

CRITICAL
10:25:05

```php
    {
    "exception": {}
   }
CRITICAL
10:25:05
request Uncaught PHP Exception Exception: "You are not allowed" at /var/www/chamilo/public/main/inc/lib/api.lib.php line 3451
{
    "exception": {}
}`
`
ExceptionLogs 2Stack Trace
Exception
Exception:
You are not allowed

  at public/main/inc/lib/api.lib.php:3451
  at api_not_allowed()
     (public/main/inc/lib/api.lib.php:1126)
  at api_block_anonymous_users()
     (public/main/auth/my_progress.php:10)    `
```

Comment: If this comes from `api_block_anonymous_users`, then this probably means it doesn't recognize you as logged in. Which could indicate problems with the PHP session.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe, not sure what I should change in php configuration, to get rid of this error

Comment: I wouldn't know either. If this doesn't come with some list of requirements that you could check against, then you might need to do a bit more debugging to figure out what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: in public/main/inc/lib/api.lib.php (line 3451)
  function api_not_allowed(    $print_headers = false,    $message = null,    $responseCode = 0) {    throw new Exception('You are not allowed');  }/** * @param string $languageIsoCode *
api_not_allowed()
in public/main/inc/lib/api.lib.php (line 1126)
function api_block_anonymous_users($printHeaders = true){    $isAuth = Container::getAuthorizationChecker()->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');    if (false === $isAuth) {        api_not_allowed($printHeaders);        return false;    }    api_block_inactive_user();