# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/html/chamilo/main/inc/lib/api.lib.php on line 702

Tags: php, php-7.4, chamilo-lms

I am now to linux and I need to install chamilo-lms. I have installed chamilo using:

- cd /tmp && wget https://github.com/chamilo/chamilo-lms/releases/download/v1.11.6/chamilo-1.11.6-php7.zip
- unzip chamilo-1.11.6-php7.zip

and php7.4

When I access the link for chamilo, I receive the following error, many times on the screen:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/html/chamilo/main/inc/lib/api.lib.php on line 702

In code, /var/www/html/chamilo/main/inc/lib/api.lib.php, it looks like this:

```php
* Vchamilo changes : allow using an alternate configuration
* to get vchamilo  instance paths
*/
function api_get_path($path = '', $configuration = [])
{
    global $paths;

    // get proper configuration data if exists
    global $_configuration;

    $emptyConfigurationParam = false;
    if (empty($configuration)) {
        $configuration = (array) $_configuration;
        $emptyConfigurationParam = true;
    }

    $course_folder = 'courses/';
    static $root_web = '';
    $root_sys = $_configuration['root_sys'];
```

I can provide additional code if needed.

I was looking what to chance to code, but I could not find or understand in order to make it work.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you,
Gabriela

Comment: Is there a reason you are installing a [version from over 5 years ago](https://github.com/chamilo/chamilo-lms/releases/tag/v1.11.6)? [Version 1.11.20](https://github.com/chamilo/chamilo-lms/releases/tag/v1.11.20) is just a couple of months old, and I think I can spot where they fixed the issue you are running into

Comment: Hi Chris,I also tried to install the last version with php 8,2 but I have the issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76811174/chamilo-lms-blank-page-and-error-after-installation...so I was trying to see if another version works :(

Comment: Version [1.11.18](https://github.com/chamilo/chamilo-lms/releases/tag/v1.11.18) from January of this year still supports PHP 7.4. Although I would absolutely recommend getting to 8.x sooner than later, maybe this will at least get you up and running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336951/message-trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-null)